# ng-tags-input not working as desired

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I am using ng-Input-tags in my angular project.But when I am searching the keyword my autocomplete is not getting updated with the searched results. I checked my method it is returning correct results but they are not appearing in dropdown of autocomplete.

This is my html code:

`<tags-input ng-model="selectedDrivers" display-property="name" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" add-from-autocomplete-only="true" placeholder="Search by driver name or driver id.."  on-tag-added="emptyScope()">
                        <auto-complete source="searchDriver($query)" debounce-delay="500"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>`

And this is my js code:

`$scope.searchDriver = function(query) {
        $scope.searchedResults = [];
        for(var key in $scope.driversInfo){
            if($scope.driversInfo[key].name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0 || $scope.driversInfo[key].id.toString().indexOf(query.toString()) >= 0)
                $scope.searchedResults.push($scope.driversInfo[key]);
        }
        return $scope.searchedResults;
    };`

Somehow the suggestionList is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source attirbute of the autocomplete is waiting for a promise so you have to use $q.

```
  let result: Array<any> = list.filter(
  (elt: any) => { return elt[property].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1; });
  deferred.resolve(result);
  return deferred.promise;
```